# How to configure uptime of my instance in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I know google charges you only for the time you use their services. My question is: Are there any ways to to schedule my instances uptime for, in example, 8 hours per day, day time only, night time only or something like that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a feature in Google Compute Engine (GCE). You will need to create your own scrip that will spin up the instance and delete it, using the [APIs in GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/#Instances).
Note that you still pay for the [persistence disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#persistentdisk) provisioned space. You can delete the instance without deleting the disk, to use the same disk to spin up the instance or you can take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#snapshots) of your disk and use it for the new instance.